# Mediawiki: Sidebar Header Link?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, mediawiki

I am trying to edit the sidebar of a mediawiki page by making a sidebar header a link.

From what I have found, the only thing that the sidebar in `[[mediawiki:sidebar]]` can interpret is asterisks.

I have attempted to do something like this:

```
* [[google.com | Help]]
** mainpage| Help
** Subheading1|Sub1
** Subheading2|Sub2
** Subheading3|Sub3
** Subheading4|Sub4
```

WHen I preview this code sample, it displays correctly. But when it is implemented, it shows the brackets and the url in the sidebar.

I assume I am going to have to do something with the "common.js", so it does it for all pages, since we are not using a skin.

**NOTE**

I do not have access to the server files since I am new here. They want me to see if I can do this editing the common.js file in [[mediawiki:common.js]].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to link to google.com, you'll have to use `http://google.com|Help`. The `MediaWiki:Sidebar` interface message is not parsed like a usual page, which leads to a confusing preview.

For more information, read the excellent [Manual for MediaWiki:Sidebar](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aInterface/Sidebar), espacially the section "Advanced customization". Try to find a non-JS solution.

Comment: I have tried reading this, but it does not help me out. I can't even get javascript to execute.

Comment: What exactly is your aim? Which rights do you have? Which JavaScript have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the clickable links from the mediawiki interface itself, You can edit the Mediawiki:Sidebar from the search as follows:

```
[[Mediawiki:Sidebar]]
* navigation
** mainpage|mainpage-description
** recentchanges-url|recentchanges
** randompage-url|randompage
** helppage|help
** https://www.google.co.in/|Google
** https://www.reddit.com/|Reddit
** https://www.google.co.in/|hi
** https://www.reddit.com/|hi1
* SEARCH
* TOOLBOX 
* LANGUAGES
```

[image]

Comment: Please refer to [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and provide some details in your answer.